# Force lshosts command to return megabytes for "maxmem" and "maxswp" parameters

Tags: linux, bash, lsf

When I type "`lshosts`" I am given:

```
HOST_NAME      type    model    cpuf   ncpus maxmem maxswp server RESOURCES
server1        X86_64 Intel_EM  60.0    12   191.9G 159.7G    Yes ()
server2        X86_64 Intel_EM  60.0    12   191.9G 191.2G    Yes ()
server3        X86_64 Intel_EM  60.0    12   191.9G 191.2G    Yes ()
```

I am trying to return `maxmem` and `maxswp` as megabytes, not gigabytes when `lshosts` is called. I am trying to send Xilinx ISE jobs to my LSF, however the software expects integer, megabyte values for `maxmem` and `maxswp`. By doing debugging, it appears that the software grabs these parameters using the `lshosts` command.

I have already checked in my lsf.conf file that:

```
LSF_UNIT_FOR_LIMTS=MB
```

I have tried searching the IBM Knowledge Base, but to no avail.

Do you use a specific command to specify `maxmem` and `maxswp` units within the lsf.conf, lsf.shared, or other config files?

Or does LSF force return the most practical unit?

Any way to override this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LSF_UNIT_FOR_LIMITS` *should* work, if you completely drained the cluster of all running, pending, and finished jobs.  According to the [docs](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSETD4_9.1.2/lsf_config_ref/lsf.conf.lsf_unit_for_limits.5.dita), `MB` is the default, so I'm surprised.

That said, you can use something like this to transform the results:

```
$ cat to_mb.awk
function to_mb(s) {
    e = index("KMG", substr(s, length(s)))
    m = substr(s, 0, length(s) - 1)
    return m * 10^((e-2) * 3)
}
{ print $1 " " to_mb($6) " " to_mb($7) }

$ lshosts | tail -n +2 | awk -f to_mb.awk
server1 191900 159700
server2 191900 191200
server3 191900 191200
```

The `to_mb` function should also handle 'K' or 'M' units, should those pop up.

Comment: I assumed 'LSF_UNIT_FOR_LIMITS' would have worked, however it seems ineffective. Cluster has been drained and restarted - still no change. From what I gather, servers with large amounts of RAM (96G and above) always show RAM in gigabytes, regardless of setting 'LSF_UNIT_FOR_LIMITS' for the sake of formatting. This is a nightmare for software that polls the 'lshosts' command for cluster info. The above function does work converting gigabytes to megabytes, however I'm trying to find a more expandable and robust solution.

Comment: Well, you could always [modify the source and compile your own](https://github.com/openlava/openlava/blob/master/lsf/lstools/lshosts.c), but personally I consider this little tool to be quite robust and consistent with the UNIX philosophy.  Of course, I'm biased. :)

Comment: Oh, and just one more note: reviewing the source code for `lshosts`, I notice that the tool itself is dumb and apparently no calculation: the final values seem to come from the server.  That suggests to me you need to set `LSF_UNIT_FOR_LIMITS` on each of the bastion hosts, not the host running `lshosts`.

Comment: I'm marking this as the correct answer because it enough to fool software by creating an alias for the command `lshosts` which would invoke this awk script. Thanks for you excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

If `LSF_UNIT_FOR_LIMITS` is defined in lsf.conf, `lshosts` will always print the output as a floating point number, and in some versions of LSF the **parameter is defined as 'KB' in lsf.conf upon installation**.

Try searching for any definitions of the parameter in lsf.conf and commenting them all out so that the parameter is left undefined, I think in that case it defaults to printing it out as an integer in megabytes.

(Don't ask me why it works this way)